# Match and Index function in excel

Tags: excel

I have following tables:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2 (to match headers with new names):

[image]

And I need following table in output:

[image]

How can I do it, I starting searching for match and index functions, but not succeeded in it

Comment: Output what? Output table showing blank cells.

Comment: You can replace old headers with VLOOKUP probably. Something like `VLOOKUP("AAAA";Table2,2,0)` should return `a`. OR if they are in the same order, just copy/paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,MATCH($B9,$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH(INDEX($F$2:$F$4,MATCH(C$8,$G$2:$G$4,0)),$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

[image]